# Connecting to host from Android via USB

Tags: android, usb, adb, portforwarding

Okay so here is the background of this problem. I commute a lot on the train and build a lot of PHP web apps optimized for mobile devices. I would like to develop code on a netbook (Running Ubuntu Server) with no GUI. All development done using Vim directly on the netbook.

I would like to connect up my Nexus 4 to the netbook via USB and "connect" to the netbooks web server in the chrome browser. I can only use USB for this since I won't be having any reliable internet access.

I understand that using `adb` from the Android SDK, you can forward a port from the netbook to the phone. However, I need to do it the other way around.

For example:

- Run a web server on the netbook on port 4000
- Connect phone via USB
- Somehow forward port 4000 on the phone to port 4000 on the netbook
- Open chrome browser on phone and go to `localhost:4000`.

I am aware of the "reverse port forwarding" method that is described in the Google docs at https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging. However, this requires an installation of chrome on the netbook. I don't want to have to install an entire GUI just for this.

**Update**

With regards to the above, I have found https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/m/#!topic/chromium-reviews/7mE61hDcFdA. Does this mean I could install Chrome on the netbook (even though I don't have a GUI) and port forward via CLI?

Answer (score 0):

An APP might do the job here. If you know some java you might be able to pull it off. Basicly you tunnel a connection through adb, then use an app as proxy and a small program on the computer. There might be an easier way though